# phonegap: Timeout error calling webviewclient

Tags: android, cordova, timeout, socket-timeout-exception

I'm trying to debug my phonegap app. When I try to open my app on my emulator I get an error saying `The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)`

I should mention that I'm using phonegap build, so I don't have any native code. The weird thing is that I'm only loading local resources, so I don't get why I'm getting a timeout. My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    <title>Mængderabat - spar mere</title>
    <script src="http://debug.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#maengderabat"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.jfeed.pack.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <style>
    .ui-li-icon{width:16px;height:16px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body >
<!-- begin first page -->
<section id="main" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>Mængderabat - spar mere</h1>
    </header>
    <div data-role="content" class="content">
        <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        </ul>
    </div>

    <footer data-role="footer">
        <h2>example by Oikos Development</h2>
    </footer>
</section>
<!-- end first page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the timeout in your main (phonegap) activity:

```
setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 30000);
```

Comment: As I said: "in your main (phonegap) activity" where you initialize the webview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with PhoneGap build but is your path to jQuery correct? I'd think it would be js/jquery* if there is a js folder in your www folder.

Also, you are loading a remote resource from debug.phonegap.com. Possibly that is slowing you down.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the path to JQuery is defined by me it's correct. Good call with the debug, unfortunately that's not what's causing the problem either. It may be something more subtle related to the phonegap build. I may have to check out the docs more thoroughly to see if I've missed something in the way the app's set up. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: You are probably better off asking from help from the PhoneGap Build guys on getsatisfaction: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/products/nitobi_phonegap_build?from_gsfn=true

Comment: Thank you Simon - I was unaware of that community. Would you care to alter your answer to a reference to that community so I can accept that as the answer, or is that against SO policy?

Comment: Meh, it's not a big deal. If you find out what the problem is just come back here and edit your question for others who may have the same problem to see the resolution.

Comment: I've the same issue, but the strange thing is I dont have any external links in my code. But still I'm getting this error. Please help me.